# How to run qjoypad?

Tags: linux, games

i started qjoypad the first time with:

> qjoypad [OPTIONEN] [PROFILNAME]

Now i always get

> Failed to find a layout named [PROFILNAME]
>   when i try to start it with only "qjoypad".

I tried deinstalling/reinstalling it via synaptic, but the problem persists.

What do i have to do?

Edit: oh, im silly, in the systray there is a icon, case closed. (you have to doubleclick it, then the GUI appears)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QJoyPad stores the name of the last layout used in a file called `layout` in its settings directory (by default, `~/.qjoypad3`). To stop it displaying the "Failed to find a layout" warning, you can delete this file:

```
rm ~/.qjoypad3/layout
```

That's just a warning though, it doesn't prevent QJoyPad from starting. As you noticed, it doesn't open a window when you start it, it adds an icon to the system tray.